# How to show different context menu strip items using radiobuttons in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a simple windows form app consisting a button(with contextmenustrip) and two radiobuttons and there are 3 menu items namely **process1**, **process2**, **process3** in the contextmenustrip.

When the button is clicked while radioButton1 is enabled only **process1**, **process2** should show and when radioButton1 is enabled only **process3** should show. How do I do this?

I tried to use the `Available` method like below but it doesn't work

```
Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
Point ptLowerLeft = new Point(0, btnSender.Height);
ptLowerLeft = btnSender.PointToScreen(ptLowerLeft);
contextMenuStrip1.Show(ptLowerLeft);
    if (radioButton1.Checked) {
        process1ToolStripMenuItem.Available=true;
        process2ToolStripMenuItem.Available=true;
        }
    if (radioButton2.Checked) {
        process2ToolStripMenuItem.Available=true;
        }
```

Comment: The default is true, focus on getting it set to false.  And try the Visible property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure to also make the other(s) unavailable depending on the situation:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    toolStripMenuItem1.Available = toolStripMenuItem2.Available = true;
    toolStripMenuItem3.Available = false;
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked)
{
    toolStripMenuItem1.Available = toolStripMenuItem2.Available = false;
    toolStripMenuItem3.Available = true;
}
```